# GitHub Extension reports 404 error for an identical repo URL that I can reach from a browser

Tags: git, github

I was working on a project in Visual Studio 2019 with GitHub Extension.

After adding a new class, I see that the GitHub Extension is no longer tracking any changes.

The GitHub Extension reports no changes.

Note this had worked earlier in the day.

I do a View | Other Windows | GitHub and launch the GitHub pane.

I click the link for my repo.  A browser launches and attempts to go to the URL for my private repo.  This returns a 404 Error with the message "This s not the web page you are looking for.

https://github.com/MyCompany/MyRepo

If I login to my GitHub account with a browser - no problem, I can reach my Repo with the same URL.

Is the GitHub Extension no longer supported?

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about a **private repository**, that's why it cannot be accessed without being logged in.

"Members of the enterprise who do not have explicit collaborator access will no longer be able to see this repository". For more info:
https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/administering-a-repository/setting-repository-visibility

You'll either have to change the visibility (`Settings -> Change visibility -> Make public`) or ensure you're logged in to GitHub.

Comment: I have been able to access the private repo from the Visual Studio Extension for GitHub for several months without any issue.  This worked Saturday morning.  This stopped working Saturday afternoon.  There were no changes made to the GitHub account at all. The first thing we noticed was that changes to source code were no longer being tracked.  When we went to the GitHub pane in Visual Studio and clicked the URL, we got a 404 error.  When I used the same URL from a browser outside of Visual Studio, I could get to the repo.  This is a flagship product. We have removed it from GitHub.